# How to pass 2 outputs from a model - Logits and attention maps to a custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am working on a model that has 2 outputs: 1st the predictions and 2nd the attention maps.
I have stored my target attention maps on my disk as '.npy' files and have loaded and stored in the runtime as reshaped_y_train_fm. I want to pass the attention maps stored by me along with the labels for every x_train.

How can I do this?

I am using the following code for creating the model:-

```py
def student_model_generator(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
    custom_fm = process_fm(x)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(custom_fm)
    predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name="predictions")(x)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[predictions, custom_fm], name='student')
```

I am using a small subset of the actual data in CIFAR-100 dataset :5 images from each category for trial(accuracy dosen't matter only the code should run).

Following is some information about the data that i am using:-

```
type of x_train <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape of x_train (500, 32, 32, 3)
type of y_train <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape of y_train (500, 100)
type of resized_y_train <class 'list'>
size of resized_y_train 500
shape of every element in resized_y_train_fm (32, 32)
```

Following is the code that i am using to call the fit method.

```py
student_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=total_loss)
student_params = student_model.fit(x_train, [y_train, resized_y_train_fm], epochs=10)
```

I am getting the following error:-

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 2
      1 student_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=total_loss)
----> 2 student_params = student_model.fit(x_train, [y_train, resized_y_train_fm], epochs=10)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py:1960, in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1953     msg += "  {} sizes: {}\n".format(
   1954         label,
   1955         ", ".join(
   1956             str(i.shape[0]) for i in tf.nest.flatten(single_data)
   1957         ),
   1958     )
   1959 msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1960 raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 500
  y sizes: 500, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples
```

How can I call the fit method to successfully train the model.